# Errors on C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have these Error That I'm not understanding tried to fixed my self but I'm still learning unity

[image: Errors]

Under I have the code

Card.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Card : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool DO_NOT = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private int state;

    [SerializeField]
    private int cardValue;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool initialized = false;

    private Sprite cardBack;
    private Sprite cardFace;

    private GameObject manager;

    void start() {
        state = 0;
        manager = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Manager");

    }

    public void setupGrapgics() {

        cardBack = manager.GetComponents<GameManager> ().getCardBack ();
        cardFace = manager.GetComponents<GameManager> ().getCardFace (cardValue);

        flipCard ();

    }

    void flipCard() {

        if(state == 0 && !DO_NOT)
            GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardBack;
        else if (state == 1 && !DO_NOT)
            GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardFace;

    }

    public int CardValue {

        get { return cardValue;}
        set { cardValue = value; }

    }

    public int State {

        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }
    }

    public bool Initialized {

        get { return initialized; }
        set { Initialized = value; }

    }

    public void falseCheck(){

        StartCoroutine (pause ());

    }

    IEnumerator pause() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    if (state == 0)
        GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardBack;
    else if (state == 1)
        GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardFace;
    DO_NOT = false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is because "FindGameObjectsWithTag" (return []), change to "FindGameObjectWithTag"

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because the method `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Manager");` returns an array and you attempt to assign the array to a non-array type. You should instead use `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Manager");` (note, no 's' in Object), which returns only the first GameObject that matches the tag.

The last two errors are related somewhat to the first, since they also return arrays. The line `manager.GetComponents<GameManager> ()` return arrays of components. To only return the first component of the given type, use `manager.GetComponent<GameManager>()`.