# Unity Keep crashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

ok had errors that I fixed and thanks you guys helped but now Unity keeps crushing when I press the run button a lot of people are saying because of the loop but I truly don't know how to fix it

GameManager.cd

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite[] cardFace;
public Sprite cardBack;
public  GameObject[] cards;
public Text macthText;

private bool _init = false;
private int _matches = 13;



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    if (!_init)
        initializecards ();

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0))
        checkCards ();

}

void initializecards(){

    for (int id = 0; id < 2; id++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            bool test = false;
            int choice = 0;
            while (!test) {
                choice = Random.Range (0, cards.Length);
                test = !(cards [choice].GetComponent<Card> ().Initialized);
            }
            cards [choice].GetComponent<Card> ().CardValue = i;
            cards [choice].GetComponent<Card> ().Initialized = true;
        }
    }

    foreach (GameObject c in cards)
        c.GetComponent<Card> ().setupGrapgics ();

    if (!_init)
        _init = true;

}

public Sprite getCardBack(){
    return cardBack;
    }

public Sprite getCardface(int i){

    return cardFace [i-1];
}

public void checkCards ()
{
    List<int> c = new List<int> ();

    for (int i = 0; i > cards.Length; i++) {

        if (cards [i].GetComponent<Card> ().State == 1)
            c.Add (i);
    }

    if (c.Count == 2)
        cardComparison (c);
}

void cardComparison(List<int> c){
    Card.DO_NOT = true;

    int x = 0;

    if (cards [c [0]].GetComponent<Card> ().CardValue == cards [c [1]].GetComponent<Card> ().CardValue) {
        x = 2;
        _matches--;
        macthText.text = "Number of Macthes: " + _matches;
        if(_matches == 0)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++){

        cards [c [i]].GetComponent<Card> ().State = x;
        cards [c [i]].GetComponent<Card> ().falseCheck ();

    }


    }
  }
```

card.cd

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Card : MonoBehaviour {

public static bool DO_NOT = false;

[SerializeField]
private int state;
[SerializeField]
private int cardValue;
[SerializeField]
private bool initialized = false;

private Sprite cardBack;
private Sprite cardFace;

private GameObject manager;

void start() {
    state = 0;
    manager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Manager");

}

public void setupGrapgics() {

    cardBack = manager.GetComponent<GameManager> ().getCardBack ();
    cardFace = manager.GetComponent<GameManager> ().getCardface     (cardValue);

    flipCard ();

}

public void flipCard() {

    if(state == 0 && !DO_NOT)
        GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardBack;
    else if (state == 1 && !DO_NOT)
        GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardFace;

}

public int CardValue {

    get { return cardValue;}
    set { cardValue = value; }


}

public int State {

    get { return state; }
    set { state = value; }
}

public bool Initialized {

    get { return initialized; }
    set { Initialized = value; }

}

public void falseCheck(){

    StartCoroutine (pause ());

}

IEnumerator pause() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    if (state == 0)
        GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardBack;
    else if (state == 1)
        GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = cardFace;
    DO_NOT = false;

}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Ask], take the [Tour] and certainly [MCVE]

Comment: Do you mean "crashing"?

Answer (score 0):

The code below freezes the game because `test` is always `false` and never `true`:

```
while (!test) {
choice = Random.Range (0, cards.Length);
test = !(cards [choice].GetComponent<Card> ().Initialized);
}
```

Tracked it down to:

```
public bool Initialized {
    get { return initialized; }
    set { Initialized = value; }
}
```

Because  `set { Initialized = value; }` should be  `set { initialized = value; }`.

NOTE:

Don't generate Random number in a while loop while using the generated number as a variable to exit the loop. If that fails, you will freeze Unity. It would be good to do that in a coroutine function then put `yield return null;` at the end of it. That will never freeze Unity.

```
while (!test) {
choice = Random.Range (0, cards.Length);
test = !(cards [choice].GetComponent<Card> ().Initialized);
yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(31,14): error CS1624: The body of `GameManager.initializecards()' cannot be an iterator block because `void' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: Like I said in the last section of my answer, you have to make it a coroutine function. `void initializecards()` should be  `IEnumerator initializecards()`. Don't just try to copy code from an answer, read what it says. And wherever you call `initializecards();` you now have to call it with `StartCoroutine (initializecards());` . For the [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41326049/3785314) you asked, you can accept one of those answers if they solved your problem.